# Expo Network issues & http:// request link doesnt open

Tags: react-native, go, expo, expo-go, go-iris

I am using my android emulator in order to develop this expo app, and once I send an email to reset password, if I send the link with ->
link := "exp://xx.x.x.xxx:8081/resetPass/",
it is not clickable in the gmail at all!

However, if I send it with ->
link := "http://xx.x.x.xxx:8081/resetPass/",
the link is clickable, and I am indeed navigating briefly to the "Reset password" screen after I click the "Click to Reset Password" link received via email,
BUT

I can see the screen as first screen for about couple milliseconds and then it starts flickering on and off between two other screens login and "This page doesn't exist".

Now, I believe the deep linking is working the right way since I can see the "Reset pass" screen briefly, right?

I am not sure what to do tho, because the expo development link in the server should start with exp:// instead of http:// in order to access the link properly, but as I previously mentioned, with exp:// is not clickable in the gmail.

I didn't add the funtionality for the resetPass yet.

What do you guys think I should be doing? Any suggestions?

Explanation in the details